# How to install Pygame on MacOS Mojave?

Tags: python, macos, gcc, pygame, macos-mojave

I'm trying to install Pygame, but this doesn't work..
I'm on Mac, using MacOs Mojave, and SublimeText.
I tried python3.8 -m pip install Pygame and python3 -m pip install -U pygame in the terminal, which is given on Pygame.org, but it prints:

`error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1`

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have an issue where macOS Mojave doesn't install all Mac SDK headers by default. Try installing them with the following command:

`sudo installer -pkg /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg -target /`

It's only an issue with Mac versions above 10.14 (included) please let me know if this fixes it